# Passing a pointer through multiple functions and getting segfault

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I'm trying to create a framework for a Room in a text game exercise. The way the game works is that Rooms are classes, which contain pointers to arrays of pointers to Tiles, and each tile has a pointer to a Container that represents items that are on the Tile.

The implementation of this is pretty simple, and it compiles fine. I'm having some problems, however, when I try to 'place' a `Thing` object 'onto' a `Tile`. This is done through passing a pointer to a Thing object through multiple passthrough functions. The pointer is passed to the Tile's `placeOnTile(Thing * i)` function, which passes it to the Tile's Container's `addItem(Thing* th)` function, which runs a simple check to make sure it fits in the Container (with a compare to a `maxSize int`), then returns true if it does fit.

According to a debug watch, the pointer (named `placer`) is not changing through the passes (this is good). However, when it reaches the final passthrough function (that of the Container's `addItem(Thing* th)`), it will segfault and not continue running the program.

The relevant code samples I could think of are listed below. If there is more I should include please let me know.

in main:

```
cout << "Bedroom Demo" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Creating bedroom obj...";
    Bedroom b1;  //this calls the constructor for Bedroom
    cout << "done." << endl << endl;
```

in Bedroom.h:

```
Bedroom()   //constructor
{
    makeNineSquare(1); //this creates an arry of 9 Tiles, arranged in a 3x3 grid
    Thing* placer;  //this will point to objects that you'll create

    placer = new Bed("Your bed","This is your bed.",false,false,true,1);  //constructor
    ti[2]->placeOnTile(placer);  //!!!!This is where the error occurs!!!!

    placer = new Decor("North-facing Window","The window to the north looks out into barren space",false,false,true);
    ti[1]->placeOnTile(placer);

    placer = new Desk("Your desk","Your desk is wooden and antique.",0,0,1,5);
    ti[3]->placeOnTile(placer);

    delete placer;  //for memory leaks
}
```

in Tile.h:

```
bool placeOnTile(Thing * i){return onTile->addItem(i);}
```

in Container.h (onTile is a Container object encapsulated in Tile):

```
bool addItem(Thing* th);
```

in Container.cpp:

```
bool Container::addItem(Thing* th)
{
     if (numItems < maxSize)
     {
         contents[++numItems] = th;
         return true;
     }
else return false;
}
```

As I mentioned above, a debug watch shows that every step of the 'passing' works fine except the final passthrough (that of Container). What am I doing wrong?

Note: ti is declared inside Bedroom. It's an array of 9 tiles, 0 through 8, that make up the 'room'. The function `makeNineSquare` is just a function that implements a two-dimensional linked list on the array, creating NESW pointers to the adjacent Tiles. The reason I've created it like this is to facilitate placement on certain tiles with the array (as shown in the code provided), and to facilitate easy traversal of the grid by an object (such as a Player) with the pointers.

This also allows for global, generic move commands (`moveN` is just `curr = curr->getN` instead of a calculation to determine if, say, 7 is adjacent to 2).

Comment: ++numItems will give you a problem I think. Say maxSize = 10. and numItems = 9. The if statement will go through fine, but numItems will be incremented to 10 and then contents will be dereferenced at 10. That would be like declaring an array with size 10 and indexing into it at 10. Only 0-9 are proper values

Comment: So, change ++numItems to numItems++ and that may fix that issue.

Comment: use `vector` or `list` rather than C array, with all those magic constants, one-off errors and such. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library Just insert new element into container and don't care a bit what is `numItems` and when to change it - it all would be done by C++ automatically for you. You also seem very wobby about what is the object, what is the pointer to it, and what are life spans for both of them, as that harmful `delete` shows. If you cannot make objects ownership and lifetime clear, then you perhaps have to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_ptr

Comment: nice introduction article (read via Google Translate or similar service) http://www.rsdn.ru/article/cpp/smartptr.xml

Comment: there was one more answer, showing that `delete` is harmful here, killing the object, pointer to which is stored in `ti[3]` and bounds of `ti` are not known and that using `ti[3]` instead of `ti[0]`  looks suspicious for C code. That answer got deleted, but since the points raised in it were valid i'd like to repeat them just for record.

Comment: What is the type of ti?

Comment: `ti` is a pointer to an array of pointers to `Tile` objects. Positions 0-8 are 'filled' with `BedroomTile` objects, whose parent is `Tile`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code I have no idea what numitems is but check if numitems++ is causing an array out of index.

Comment: numItems is the number of items in the Container object. It's set to 0 on creation, no matter what constructor is used.